# Question about number of features in a paper

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

In [this](https://aclanthology.org/P13-1162.pdf) paper it states that there are 36,787 features, although in Table 3 it states there are clearly 32.

Also how are the words encoded? Is this a one hot encoding they are working with here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details, you should probably e-mail the authors, but notice that Table 3 just mentions the classes of the features. For example, *Position in sentence* has three categories, so after one-hot encoding, this makes three features, *Polarity* has over three categories, so few more features, *Word* are probably one-hot encoded unique words, so there could be thousands of them, same with *Lemma*. Easily this may go into thousands.

Comment: OK thats make sense. Didn't now that each of the one-hot encoding bits counts as a feature. Thank you! Actually I am just aware of Word2Vec models for encoding words. Is there a lexicon for one hot encodings of words that I am not aware of? Since back then there was no Word2Vec.

Comment: A vector that I get from the Word2Vec model is a single feature? Or is every bit a single feature actually?

Comment: @craaaft I don't understand your questions. If you want to use a particular implementation of a model (like Word2Vec) just look at the documentation of the format of the inputs. As about the definition of features, in general, "feature" is any column (in tabular data) of numbers, for example, if you one-hot encode words, it creates binary features to encode the words.